# Scan paired cells of two columns for the same pattern using Python

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner and would like to learn how to use it for operations on text files. I have an input txt file of 4 columns separated by TAB, and I want to search whether, row by row, the cell pairs in columns 1 and 4 simultaneously contain the pattern "BBB" or "CCC". If true, send the whole line to output1. If false, send the whole line to output2.

This is the input.txt:

```
more input.txt

AABBBAA 2   5   AACCCAA
AAAAAAA 4   10  AAAAAAA
AABBBAA 6   15  AABBBAA
AAAAAAA 8   20  AAAAAAA
AACCCAA 10  25  AACCCAA
AAAAAAA 12  30  AAAAAAA
```

This is the Python code I wrote:

```
more main.py
```

```
import sys

input = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
output1 = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
output2 = open(sys.argv[3], "w")

list = ["BBB", "CCC"]

for line in input:
    for item in list:
        if item in line.split("\t")[0] and item in line.split("\t")[3]:
            output1.write(line)
        else:
            output2.write(line)

input.close()
output1.close()
output2.close()
```

Command:

```
python main.py input.txt output1.txt output2.txt
```

output1.txt is correct

```
more output1.txt
```

```
AABBBAA 6   15  AABBBAA
AACCCAA 10  25  AACCCAA
```

output2 is incorrect. I'm trying to understand why it takes both the lines of output1.txt and the double copy of the other lines.

```
more output2.txt
```

```
AABBBAA 2   5   AACCCAA
AABBBAA 2   5   AACCCAA
AAAAAAA 4   10  AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA 4   10  AAAAAAA
AABBBAA 6   15  AABBBAA
AAAAAAA 8   20  AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA 8   20  AAAAAAA
AACCCAA 10  25  AACCCAA
AAAAAAA 12  30  AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA 12  30  AAAAAAA
```

output2.txt should be:

```
AABBBAA 2   5   AACCCAA
AAAAAAA 4   10  AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA 8   20  AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA 12  30  AAAAAAA
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't use python builtins (like `list` or `input`) for variable names. Doing this hides the original meaning of those words. This is general advice unrelated to your problem

Comment: You get duplicated lines in `output2` because you ask it to do so. Your condition is: If `item` exists in both columns, write the line to `output1`, else write it to `output2`. Then you proceed to do this for each `item` in `list`. Since there are two items in `list`, and (e.g. in line 1) the first item doesn't exist in both columns, it writes the line once to `output2`, then the second item doesn't exist in both columns either, so it writes the line again to `output2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. As a beginner, it is much appreciated.

Comment: You might find it useful to read [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
and
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
If writing code is one side of the programming coin, debugging is the other side. You can't have one without the other. The sooner into your programming career you learn how to debug your own (and other people's) code the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get duplicated lines in `output2` because you ask it to do so. Your condition is: If `item` exists in both columns, write the line to `output1`, else write it to `output2`. Then you proceed to do this for each `item` in `list`. Since there are two items in `list`, and (e.g. in line 1) the first item doesn't exist in both columns, it writes the line once to `output2`, then the second item doesn't exist in both columns either, so it writes the line again to `output2`.

Let's restate your condition:

> [Check if] the cell pairs in columns 1 and 4 simultaneously contain the pattern "BBB" or "CCC". If true, send the whole line to output1. If false, send the whole line to output2.

So for each row, you want to check if *any* <sup>(`any`)</sup> of the items in `list`<sup>(`for item in lst`)</sup> occur in *both* those columns<sup>(`item in cols[0] and item in cols[3]`)</sup>.

```
lst = ["BBB", "CCC"]
for line in input_file:
    cols = line.split("\t")
    if any(item in cols[0] and item in cols[3] for item in lst):
        output1.write(line)
    else:
        output2.write(line)
```

<sup>Note that I renamed `list` to `lst` and `input` to `input_file` in my code to avoid shadowing the builtins</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `else` part of the `if` statement. As every time the `if` condition doesn't return `True` you are writing the line to the output2.txt file, which is not the logic you want.

You will need to change the logic of the code to make it only write to output2.txt, if both 'BBB' and 'CCC' are not found.